# google-api-python-client broken because of OAuth2?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I am trying to check if a certain dataset exists in bigquery using the Google Api Client in Python. It always worked untill the last update where I got this strange error I don't know how to fix:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dsUtils/bq_utils.py", line 106, in _get
    resp = bq_service.datasets().get(projectId=self.project_id, datasetId=self.id).execute(num_retries=2)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 755, in execute
    method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 93, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 598, in new_request
    self._refresh(request_orig)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 864, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 891, in _do_refresh_request
    body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1597, in _generate_refresh_req
uest_body
    assertion = self._generate_assertion()
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 263, in _generate_ass
ertion
    key_id=self._private_key_id)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 97, in make_signed_jwt
    signature = signer.sign(signing_input)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 101, in sign
    return PKCS1_v1_5.new(self._key).sign(SHA256.new(message))
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py", line 112, in sign
    m = self._key.decrypt(em)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 174, in decrypt
    return pubkey.pubkey.decrypt(self, ciphertext)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/pubkey.py", line 93, in decrypt
    plaintext=self._decrypt(ciphertext)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 235, in _decrypt
    r = getRandomRange(1, self.key.n-1, randfunc=self._randfunc)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 123, in getRandomRange
    value = getRandomInteger(bits, randfunc)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 104, in getRandomInteger
    S = randfunc(N>>3)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 202, in read
    return self._singleton.read(bytes)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 178, in read
    return _UserFriendlyRNG.read(self, bytes)
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 137, in read
    self._check_pid()
  File "/root/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 153, in _check_pid
    raise AssertionError("PID check failed. RNG must be re-initialized after fork(). Hint: Try Random.atfork()")
AssertionError: PID check failed. RNG must be re-initialized after fork(). Hint: Try Random.atfork()
```

Is someone understanding what is hapening?

Note that I also get this error with other bricks like GCStorage.

Note also that I use the following command to load my Google credentials:

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

def get_credentials(credentials_path):  #my json credentials path
    logger.info('Getting credentials...')
    try:
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials_path
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        return credentials
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

So if anyone know a better way to load my google credentials using my json service account file, and which would avoid the error, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the error is in the PyCrypto module, which appears to be used under the hood by Google's OAuth2 implementation. If your code is calling `os.fork()` at some point, you may need to call `Crypto.Random.atfork()` afterward in both the parent and child process in order to update the module's internal state.

See here for PyCrypto docs; search for "atfork" for more info:
https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto

This question and answer might also be relevant:
[PyCrypto : AssertionError("PID check failed. RNG must be re-initialized after fork(). Hint: Try Random.atfork()")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981503/pycrypto-assertionerrorpid-check-failed-rng-must-be-re-initialized-after-fo)

Comment: I don't use os.fork() but I am using p = Process(target=main.launch_workflow, args=(account_id, exports_date)).start(), the Process() class coming from the multiprocessing module. Where can I write this Crypto.Random.atfork()?

Comment: I already tried to write it just after the Process().start and just at the beginning of the main.launch function the new process is calling, but It still does not work.

Comment: It looks like oauth2client prefers openssl for crypto if that's available. Instead of using PyCrypto, maybe OpenSSL will work in your scenario? https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/crypt.py