# 403 Error uploading data to Google Storage with Python SDK after calling fork()

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, fork, python-3.6

I am trying to upload content to a Google bucket using Python SDK in a forked process on a Linux host (Ubuntu 18.04)
The operation fails with status code 403:

> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/temp-compare/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', )

Example code:

```
import random
import string
import json
import os
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_to_bucket(plainText):
    gcp_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("/path/to/google-bucket-credentials.json")
    bucket = gcp_client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
    bucket_file_name = random_file_name('json', 10)
    blob = bucket.blob(bucket_file_name)
    blob.upload_from_string(plainText)
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=48), method="GET")
    return url

def random_file_name(ext, length):
    return "%s.%s" % (''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(length)), ext)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.fork()
    url = upload_to_bucket("just for test")
    res = requests.get(url)
    print(res.content.decode('utf8'))
```

I have tried using the solutions offered in [google-api-python-client broken because of OAuth2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498370/google-api-python-client-broken-because-of-oauth2) with no lock.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not surprisingly it turns out i'm the source of the problem.
After forking the process the random filename created by `random_file_name` is the same (probably has something to do with the way a seed is generated)
Since the account does not have permission to override the file it gets a 403 response.

If I change `random_file_name` to be:

```
def random_file_name(ext, length):
    import uuid
    return  str(uuid.uuid4())[0:length]+"."+ext
```

All is working as expected.

I would probably be still looking for a solution if it not for @TasosZG advise to use the cloud shell.

Comment: Python has a "pseudo-random" number generator. This means it generates the same set of numbers each time it is called. As with most random number generators you need to "seed" them to increase entropy. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Answer (score 3):

The issue doesn't seem to be with `fork()` but with the authentication with the service account. Does it work for you without `fork()`?

I ran your code and managed to upload and read the content of the file, both with and without `fork()`.

For the authentication with a service account json key I did the following:

1. Go to Console -> IAM & admin -> Service accounts -> Create service account
2. Grant it the Storage -> Storage Admin role
3. Create key (json) and save it in a file `key.json` in the same folder with my code
4. Configure the code to authenticate by reading the key of that file `client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("key.json")`

And it worked. When I changed the role of the service account to have fewer permissions, it failed giving me a similar error to yours, only it also told me that the service account I used doesn't have `storage.buckets.get` access on that bucket.

Comment: When i comment out the fork() it works. it even works if only one forked process is trying to upload. Did you try it from linux host or windows host? I probably should have stated in the beginning that the issue is from Linux - It will not reproduce on windows (I think python fork is not really implemented on windows)

Comment: Further more, I am pretty sure the issue is related to some cryptography library that the SDK is using that does not work with fork.

Comment: @ErezBenHarush I tried it from a linux Compute Engine VM and from the Cloud Shell. The library version I used is this `google-cloud-storage==1.13.2`. Which version are you using? and have you tried from the Cloud Shell?

Comment: I just tried it with the latest version (1.15.0), and it worked again. I started from scratch. Created a VM with Ubuntu 19.04, set up the [Python environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup), installed the library, copied the key and ran the code. Could you try from other environments like a Compute Engine VM or the Cloud Shell to see if it works?

Comment: first of all, I appreciate your help.  I am using google-cloud-storage=1.15.0. It also fails on cloud shell using google-cloud-storage=1.14.0 (By fail i mean upload from one forked process is OK and the second is 403)

Comment: If i remove the fork and run it in a loop a few times it works like a charm, Maybe now is a good time to mention i am using python3 but it also fail in python2

Comment: I tried with `Python 2.7.16 & 3.5.3 & 3.7.3`, with `Python 3.7.3` 2 files are uploaded as expected. With `Python 2.7.16 & 3.5.3` only 1 file is uploaded but it doesn't throw any error and both print the contents of the file (as if both processes upload the same filename). Which exact version of Python3 are you using?